# Selecting a date range where date is not null with Propel

Tags: symfony1, propel, date-range

Using Propel I would like to find records which have a date field which is not null and also between a specific range.

N.B. Unfortunately, as this is part of a larger query, I cannot utilise a custom SQL query here.

**For example: I may have records like this:**

```
---------------------
| ID | DUE_DATE     |
---------------------
| 1  |  NULL        |
| 2  |  01/01/2010  |
| 3  |  02/01/2010  |
| 4  |  NULL        |
| 5  |  05/01/2010  |
---------------------
```

I may want to return all the rows with a due_date between 01/01/2010 and 02/01/2010 but I don't want to return those records where due_date is NULL.

**In the example I only want to return rows 2 and 3.**

However, Propel seems to overwrite my NOTNULL criteria.

**Is it possible to do this with Propel?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you create the separate `Criterion` objects?

```
$start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+$start, date("Y"));
$end_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+$end, date("Y"));

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(TaskPeer::DUE_DATE, $end_date, Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
$c->addAnd(TaskPeer::DUE_DATE, $start_date, Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
$c->addAnd(TaskPeer::DUE_DATE, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
```

When I try this in Propel 1.2, 1.3 or 1.4, I get the following SQL statement:

`SELECT task.TASK_ID, task.DUE_DATE FROM task WHERE ((task.DUE_DATE<=:p1 AND task.DUE_DATE>=:p2) AND task.DUE_DATE IS NOT NULL )`

The `$c->add()` method *replaces* the current criterion for the given field. You create your Criterions for `TaskPeer::DUE_DATE`, so they will always replace the previous ones.

Comment: Ok - I probably just need to upgrade to Propel 1.4 don't I! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I re-tested this in Propel 1.2 and 1.3, and I get the same results. So while you can upgrade (maybe choose 1.5 now, it is stable and much nicer for query building), you don't have to.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for going back and testing that for me. I won't have chance to look at this issue again until this evening.

Answer (score 2):

I did't get *remove the null entries* section, I think it will produce: `tasks.due_date IS NULL AND tasks.due_date IS NULL`.

Anyway, maybe you can use `Criteria::CUSTOM` to write raw-SQL WHERE clause? Example from Propel [documentation](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.4/Criteria):

```
$con = Propel::getConnection(ReviewPeer::DATABASE_NAME);

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ReviewPeer::REVIEW_DATE, 'to_date('.ReviewPeer::REVIEW_DATE.', \'YYYY-MM-DD\') = '.$con->quote($date->format('Y-m-d'), Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, custom SQL is not possible with what I am doing as this is part of a larger query.